# How to get faster result of ManagementObject

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I'm created method for collecting installed applications version info from windows OS. But facing slowness issue, when assign the value into foreach. Getting ManagementObjectSearcher result is faster. Any suggestion for my requirement?

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name=Google Chrome");

foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) // this part is taking too long time to process
{
    MessageBox.Show(obj["Name"] + "-----" + obj["Version"]);
};
```

Comment: The actual query is executed in the `Get()` method. Not when the `ManagementObjectSearcher` is created

Comment: I see, anyway suggestion to Get() result faster?

Comment: One thing that helps is to query only the needed properties. Like SELECT Name, Version instead of SELECT *

Comment: Don't use System.Management for this: it interacts with the installer is a weird manner. Whatever you do, it checks the current status and waits for the results. Either use this: [Using Windows Installer to Inventory Products and Patches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/inventory-products-and-patches) (i.e., [MsiEnumProductsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msienumproductsexw) & Co.) or parse the Registry directly.